# QNX resource manager full duplex or half duplex

Tags: resources, qnx, rtos

I am using a resource manager to read the data from the communication channel and send it to the application. I have doubt, is the QNX resource manager half duplex or full duplex?

Can simultaneous read/write work with QNX resource manager?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is full duplex. You can read and write. The actual read/write mechanism can differ depending on the resource and driver used, but all pathnames are designed to be read-write.